# jQuery UI Accordion not being resized to content

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, accordion

I have 2 accordions with 2 panels in my asp.net-mvc4 view. Panels for first accordion are resized to their content height but I do not know why panels for second accordion are not being resized to their content. Both accordions are exactly the same... so what's wrong?

In the second accordion, panels appear with vertical scrollbars, and I do not want it. See below at: http://snag.gy/3hld2.jpg

As you can see first panel for accordion is showing vertical scrollbar and it does not resize to its content. Also happens for second panel.

View:

```
        <div id="accordion2" style ="width: 790px;">
           <div class="group">
             <h3>Filters</h3>                     
             <div>
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController",
                   new AjaxOptions
                   {
                       HttpMethod = "GET",
                       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                       UpdateTargetId = "jqGrid",
                       OnSuccess = "showGrid()"
                   }))
                {
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td> 
                            <div id = "TypeFilter">
                                @Html.LabelFor(...)
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(...)
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td id="ApplyFilter" >
                            <input type="submit" name="_search" value="@Resource.CaptionApplyFilter" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                }
             </div>
           </div> <!-- end group -->
           <div class="group">
             <h3>Add item</h3>

             <div>
                 @using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction2", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
                 { 
                     <table>
                         <tr>
                             <td>
                                 <div id="itemId">
                                     @Html.LabelFor(...)
                                     @Html.DropDownListFor(...)
                                 </div>
                             </td>
                             <td>     
                                 <label for="Name">Name:</label>                     
                                 @Html.TextBox("Name", null, new { @class = "textStyle" })
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <label for="Desc">Desc.:</label> 
                                 @Html.TextBox("Desc", null, new { @class = "textStyle" })
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <input id="submitAdd" type="submit" value="@Resource.ButtonTitleAdd" />
                             </td>
                         </tr>                                
                     </table>
                 }
             </div>
           </div>  <!--end group -->
        </div> <!-- end accordion -->
```

Script in view:

```
    $(function () {
        function subscribe_accordion_to_hoverintent_event(accordionId) {
            $(accordionId).accordion({
                header: "> div > h3",
                event: "click hoverintent"
            });
        }

        subscribe_accordion_to_hoverintent_event("#accordion1");
        subscribe_accordion_to_hoverintent_event("#accordion2");
    });

    // Collapse content
    $(function () {
        function set_accordion_as_collapsible(accordionId) {
            $(accordionId).accordion({
                collapsible: true//,
                //heightStyle: "content"
            });
        }

        set_accordion_as_collapsible("#accordion1");
        set_accordion_as_collapsible("#accordion2");
    });

    // Sortable functionality
    $(function () {
        function set_accordion_as_sortable(accordionId) {
            $(accordionId).sortable({
                  axis: "y",
                  handle: "h3",
                  stop: function (event, ui) {
                             // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
                             // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
                             ui.item.children("h3").triggerHandler("focusout");
                  }
            });
        }

        set_accordion_as_sortable("#accordion1");
        set_accordion_as_sortable("#accordion2");
    });

    /*
    * hoverIntent | Copyright 2011 Brian Cherne
    * http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html
    * modified by the jQuery UI team
    */
    $.event.special.hoverintent = {
        setup: function () {
            $(this).bind("mouseover", jQuery.event.special.hoverintent.handler);
        },
        teardown: function () {
            $(this).unbind("mouseover", jQuery.event.special.hoverintent.handler);
        },
        handler: function (event) {
            var currentX, currentY, timeout,
args = arguments,
target = $(event.target),
previousX = event.pageX,
previousY = event.pageY;
            function track(event) {
                currentX = event.pageX;
                currentY = event.pageY;
            };
            function clear() {
                target
.unbind("mousemove", track)
.unbind("mouseout", clear);
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            }
            function handler() {
                var prop,
orig = event;
                if ((Math.abs(previousX - currentX) +
Math.abs(previousY - currentY)) < 7) {
                    clear();
                    event = $.Event("hoverintent");
                    for (prop in orig) {
                        if (!(prop in event)) {
                            event[prop] = orig[prop];
                        }
                    }
                    // Prevent accessing the original event since the new event
                    // is fired asynchronously and the old event is no longer
                    // usable (#6028)
                    delete event.originalEvent;
                    target.trigger(event);
                } else {
                    previousX = currentX;
                    previousY = currentY;
                    timeout = setTimeout(handler, 100);
                }
            }
            timeout = setTimeout(handler, 100);
            target.bind({
                mousemove: track,
                mouseout: clear
            });
        }
    };
```